# Why are schema capitalizations inconsistent in Visual Studio database projects?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, database-schema, database-project

So I've run into a somewhat maddening bug (perhaps) with Visual Studio database projects, specifically in 2010 Ultimate.

Basically, let's say I have two .schema.sql files, like so:

File 1

```
CREATE SCHEMA [Test]
GO
```

File2

```
CREATE SCHEMA [AuditTest]
GO
```

This compiles down and is deployed as:

```
PRINT N'Creating [AuditTest]...';


GO
CREATE SCHEMA [AuditTest]
    AUTHORIZATION [dbo];


GO
PRINT N'Creating [test]...';


GO
CREATE SCHEMA [test]
    AUTHORIZATION [dbo];
```

**So it (seemingly arbitrarily) chose to abandon my choice of capitalization.**

Why God?  **Why?!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'd still love to know if this is a legitimate bug, but I got the output I wanted by opting for this:

```
CREATE SCHEMA Test
```

over this

```
CREATE SCHEMA [Test]
```

for all my schemas.  In case anyone else ever runs into this.